# Regular Expression - 301 redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have the below URL

```
http://www.yyyyy.com/en/x/y/2010/2010-02-03-test
```

And I want to redirect it to

```
https://www.yyyyy.com/x/y/2010-02-03-test
```

So what I need to do is, remove the `/en/` part from the URL

I need the regular expression to add on `.htaccess` file that can help me to do 301 redirects for this,

Comment: And what's exactly your problem with the regular expression? Or maybe you just want anybody else to do your job?

Comment: Concerning the language part, you could use the standard codes to do the detection, such as ISO 639-1 codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes. I guess there are some web apis that provide the full list. Obviously, that works only if your URLs are formatted using the said codes... For your regex, WTH did you try in the first place ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following redirect:

```
 RedirectMatch ^/en/x/y/2010/(.+)$ /x/y/$1
```